# Where are "for" and "move" commands located?

Tags: windows, cmd

I need to run a for / move command,

```
for %F in (C:\Users\Jackson\*.*) do move /Y %F c:\foo
```

But I keep getting

> ```
> The system cannot find the file specified.
> ```

Where are `for` and `move` located?

I've searched in `C:\Windows\System32` but they are not there...

Comment: These are internal commands of Windows command processor `cmd.exe` which processes a batch file.

Comment: The correct command line would be `for %I in ("%UserProfile%\*") do move /Y "%I" "C:\foo\"`. But the user's profile directory contains files which should be never moved like the registry hive file of the current user and this file cannot be moved on current user logged on.

Comment: You should try quotation: `move /Y "%~F" "C:\foo"`...

Comment: Hint: If the execution of `%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe command` does not return full qualified file name of `command`, but `command /?` works and outputs the help for this command, the `command` is an internal command of Windows command processor.

Comment: Last hint: Command `move` supports also a wildcard pattern for files to move. So possible would be also just `move /Y "%UserProfile%\*" "C:\foo\"` without usage of `for`.

Comment: A list of cmd.exe internal commands; including FOR and MOVE. https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html

Comment: If you had a problem with `for` or `move`, you'd get "... was not recognized as internal or external command ...`. It's the `%F` which makes trouble when the file name has a space. Quoting (as suggested by Mofi and aschipfl) solves that issue. Voted to close as "a simple typographical error"